# How to use fetch with Authorization Header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, fetch

I'm quite new to using fetch and I dont know if I'm doing this right since it works fairly well with POST. If I use the normal fetch method, and not the function I made, the server responds with the data. But if I use this, the data becomes undefined. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

**network_requests.js**

```
export const getData = (url, data) => {
    return fetch(url, {
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // must match 'Content-Type' header
        cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: 'include', // include, same-origin, *omit
        headers: {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 MDN Example',
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Token '+ localStorage.token
        },
        method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
        redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
        referrer: 'no-referrer', // *client, no-referrer
    })
        .then(response => response.json()); // parses response to JSON
};
```

**sample usage: (doesnt work)**

```
fetchDrivers() {
    return getData('/members/drivers').then(data => {
        if (!data["error"]) {
            //for each entry in drivers data, append data as a dictionary in tableData
            //ant tables accept values {"key": value, "column_name" : "value" } format
            //I cant just pass the raw array since its a collection of objects
            const tableData = [];
            //append drivers with their ids as key
            data["drivers"].forEach(item => tableData.push({
                "key": item.id,
                "name": item.name
            }));
            this.setState({drivers: tableData});
        } else {
            console.log(data["error"]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you still get the error if you change from `Token` to `token`?

Comment: Yes unfortunately, the request header is sent but the data becomes undefined for some reason.

Comment: "it works fairly well with POST" — So why did you say `method: 'GET'`?

Comment: `getData = (url, data)` and `getData('/members/drivers')`. Are you sure you only wanted to send one argument?

Comment: `'content-type': 'application/json',` — why are you sending that on a GET request?

Comment: "But if I use this, the data becomes undefined." — What else happens? Does the Console display any error messages? Can you see the request in the Network tab? Is the request formatted the way you expect? Does it get a response? How much does the response differ from what you expect?

Comment: "the data becomes undefined" — How can you tell? Do you get an exception when you attempt to test `if (!data["error"])`?

Comment: Hello, I'm also open to just using fetch my only issue is how to append an Authorization Token to it. I just posted my current test since it worked well for a post version

Comment: What happens if you just write `return fetch(url, { headers: { Authorization: 'Token '+ localStorage.token } }).then(res => res.json());`, as a test?

Comment: @Tholle hello, I tested this method and I found something new. Apparently my token is considered invalid but I'm not sure why. Do I have to stringify my token?

Comment: @Jason Maybe you want to do `localStorage.getItem('token')`? I'm not sure.